# oracle 11 :want to pass cursor variable to variable defined in procedure

Tags: oracle11g

Previously i used a temp table which created outside the procedure and inserted data in SP and used,,,but if i want to create a temp table inside procedure it throwing some errors..to avoid that trying to using cursor..

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE P_EMAIL_update
AS
   I    NUMBER := 1;
   J    NUMBER := 0;
   ID   NUMBER;
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO ENTITY_TEMP                                    --(RN,ENTITY_ID)
      SELECT ROWNUM, e.id
        FROM entity e, company c
       WHERE e.companyid = c.id AND e.status = 3;

   SELECT MAX (rn) INTO j FROM ENTITY_TEMP;

   WHILE i <= j
   LOOP
      SELECT entity_id
        INTO id
        FROM ENTITY_TEMP
       WHERE rn = i;

      INSERT INTO ACTIONS_EMAIL_MAPPING (ID,
                                         ISACTIVE,
                                         ACTIONNAME,
                                         EMAILFROM,
                                         EMAILSUBJECT,
                                         EMAILBODY
                                         )
         (SELECT SEQ_ENT.NEXTVAL,
                 'N',
                 ACTIONNAME,
                 EMAILFROM,
                 EMAILSUBJECT,
                 EMAILBODY || var_id
            FROM ACTIONS
           WHERE ISACTIVE = 'T' AND ACTIONNAME NOT IN ('sample'));

      I := I + 1;
   END LOOP;
   END;
```

Comment: Please post some sample data and needed result, clearly explaining what you need to do. As is, it's hard for me to understand what your code should do. For example, if you want to get a max value from a table, why do you need a cursor? And why do you ask how to pass a cursor, if your procedure has no parameters?, ...

Comment: Previously i used a temp table which created outside the procedure and inserted data in SP and used,,,but if i want to create a temp table inside procedure it throwing some errors..to avoid that trying to using cursor..

Comment: Again, please post some sample data and needed result, clearly explaining what you need to do

Comment: Sounds like you simply need a `select count(*) from emp e...` sql statement? Or, if you need all the rows from the cursor, a `count(*) over ()` analytic function to return the count across all rows?

Comment: Based on your updated question, it now looks like you need a single insert statement. I have several questions: 1. there is no link between the select from the actions and entity_temp tables - do you really mean to insert the same set of rows from the actions table x times, where x is the number of rows in the entity_temp table? 2. Why are you using a while loop instead of, say, the more standard cursor-for-loop? That way, you wouldn't need to find the count, nor would you need to reselect from the table to find the id. 3. Is `var_id` a column of the actions table? If not, it's not declared.

Comment: id only it not Var_id..

Comment: that is ID only..not Var_id

Comment: how can i use cursor instead of temp table ..please explain

Answer (score 0):

The procedure in your question could be rewritten more simply as:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p_email_update AS
BEGIN

  INSERT INTO actions_email_mapping (id, isactive, actionname, emailfrom, emailsubject, emailbody)
  SELECT seq_ent.nextval,
         'N',
         a.actionname,
         a.emailfrom,
         a.emailsubject,
         a.emailbody || ent.id -- assuming var_id is a column of actions
  FROM   actions a
         CROSS JOIN (SELECT e.id
                     FROM   entity e
                            inner join company c on e.companyid = c.id
                     WHERE  e.status = 3) ent -- maybe this should be an inner join with some join conditions?
  WHERE  a.isactive = 'T'
  AND    a.actionname NOT IN ('sample');

END p_email_update;
/
```

There is no need to reinvent a cross join (which is what your code was doing, in a very roundabout way). There is also no need to store the data in a temp table either, based on what you've told us in your question, since you can just reference the subquery directly in the insert-as-select.

I would question why there aren't any join conditions between your actions table, and the subquery on the entity and company tables, though.